# Sed replace domain in URL

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have these strings `http://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx`, `https://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx` and `https://domain.com`

Is it possible to use `sed` to replace only the domain part?

For example, this URL:

```
http://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx
```

Would become:

```
http://anotherdomain.com/myuri/default.aspx
```

Please note that the protocol may differ between `https` and `http`.

I did search but could not find something similar.

Comment: Can you have URL with `http://` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need non-greedy pattern that `sed` can't offer, use perl instead:

`perl -pe '/(http|https):\/\/(.*?)(\/|$)/ && s/$2/anotherdomain/g'`

**Edit:**
`awk` also does the job well and it's even simpler actually:

```
awk -F/ 'gsub($3,"anotherdomain",$0)' <<< "$urls"
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

urls=$(cat << 'EOF' 
https://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx
http://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx
http://blabla
EOF
)
perl -pe '/(http|https):\/\/(.*?)(\/|$)/ && s/$2/anotherdomain/g' <<< "$urls"
```

Output:

```
bash test.sh 
https://anotherdomain/myuri/default.aspx
http://anotherdomain/myuri/default.aspx
http://anotherdomain
```

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your question, then yes `sed 's/sub\.domain\.com/anotherdomain\.com/1'` -

```
echo "http://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx" | \
  sed 's/sub\.domain\.com/anotherdomain\.com/1'
```

Output is

```
http://anotherdomain.com/myuri/default.aspx
```

And with,

```
echo "https://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx" | \
  sed 's/sub\.domain\.com/anotherdomain\.com/1'
```

Output is

```
https://anotherdomain.com/myuri/default.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed like this:

```
sed -r 's|(https?://)[^/]+([[^:blank:]]*)|\1anotherdomain.com\2|g' file
http://anotherdomain.comn.com/myuri/default.aspx
https://anotherdomain.comn.com/myuri/default.aspx
https://anotherdomain.comn.com
```

**PS:** Use `sed -E` on OSX.

Comment: url="https://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx"


`echo $url | sed -r 's|(https?://)[^/]+([[^:blank:]]*)|\1anotherdomain.com\2|g'`


https://anotherdomain.comn.com/myuri/default.aspx

Almost there. :)

Comment: Not sure why the line breaks fails. Sorry about that. :/

Comment: `url='https://sub.domain.com/myuri/default.aspx'; echo "$url" | gsed -r 's|(https?://)[^/]+([[^:blank:]]*)|\1anotherdomain.com\2|g'` will give you `https://anotherdomain.comn.com/myuri/default.aspx`. This is your expected output right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

```
SERVER=www.example.com
sed "s~https\?://\([^/]\+\)\(.*\)~http://$SERVER\2~" <<< "http://newsub.domain.com/myuri/default
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @hek2mgl's solution:

```
SERVER=www.example.com
sed "s=\(https\?://\)[^/]\+=\1$SERVER=" \
    <<< 'https://anotherdomain.com/myuri/default.aspx'
```

It will output:

```
https://www.example.com/myuri/default.aspx
```

Modifications from hek2mgl's `sed` line:

- a little shorter (no need to catch the part after domain name to paste it as is in replacement)
- deals with both `http://` and `https://` syntax